# How to pass changes from middleware to socket.io?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am using node.js with socket.io to push real time notifications to users. However, currently I am just sending back a query result done in my socket.io code and sending it back to the client but I need to let socket know about the changes that occur and to either update with the changes or re-query the db to check for the new number and send that to the client.

For example if a user gets a friend request then the notification count will change and I want socket.io to push the new notification count number to the user.

here is my socket.io code in my app.js file:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var sessionID = socket.handshake.sessionID,
    session = new connect.middleware.session.Session({ sessionStore: sessionStore }, socket.handshake.session)
  console.log('socket: new ' + sessionID)
  socket.broadcast.emit('arpNewConn', session.passport.user)
       var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    socket.handshake.session.reload(function() {
      socket.handshake.session.touch().save()
    })
    socket.emit('pulse', { heartbeat: new Date().toString(), timestamp: new Date().getTime() })
  }, 300 * 1000)


      socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      console.log('socket: dump ' + sessionID)
      socket.broadcast.emit('arpLostConn', session.passport.user)
      clearInterval(intervalID)
    })
      socket.emit('entrance', {message: 'Message works'});
      dbnotif.findOne(userID, function (err, user) {   
        if(err) throw err;
        notify = user.notifications;
        socket.emit('notify', {notific: notify});
      });
  });
```

Here is the client side:

```
div#CheckSocket

    script(src='http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js')
    script.

        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log('socket');
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/');
            console.log('entered1');

            socket.on('entrance', function  (data) {
                console.log('entered');
                console.log(data.message);
            });

            socket.on('notify', function  (data) {
                console.log('noting');
                console.log(data.notific);
                if(data.notific !== 0)
                    $('.notifications').html(data.notific);
            });

            socket.on('reconnecting', function(data) {
                setStatus('reconnecting');
                console.log('entered2');
            });

            function setStatus(msg) {
                console.log('connection status: ' + msg);
                console.log('entered5');
            }

        });
```

Here is the example of adding a friend in the route file:

```
exports.addContactPost = function(req, res, err) {
  async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {
            var success;
            var newFriend = new Friend ({
                userId: req.signedCookies.userid,
                friend_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.otherUser),
                friend_status: 1
            });
            newFriend.save(function(err){
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("saved it");
                     success = true;
                }
            });
            callback(null, success)
        },
        function(success, callback) {
            //if(success === true) {
                var success2;
                var newFriend2 = new Friend ({
                    userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.otherUser),
                    friend_id: req.signedCookies.userid,
                    friend_status: 2
                });
                newFriend2.save(function(err){
                    if(err) {
                        res.send("request not received");
                    } else {
                        success2 = true;
                    }
                });
                callback(null, success2);
            //} else {
            //  res.send("error with request sent");
            //}

        },

        function(success2, callback) {
            console.log('callback3');
            //if(success2 === true) { 
                var success3;
                Notification.findOneAndUpdate({userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.otherUser)}, {
                        $inc: {notifications: 1}
                    }, function(err, notify) {
                        if(err) { 
                            res.send(err); 
                        } else {
                            console.log(notify);
                            if(notify.added_notifications === true) {
                            // enable mail and include general u have got a new request... do not include name because not storing it

                            }
                        }
                        success3 = true;
                        callback(null, success3);

        }],

    function(err, results) {
            res.json({response: true});
            console.log("Add successful");


    });
};
```

Notes: dbnotif is a model being called by mongoose,
userID is a global variable available to the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I helped him solve this question offline, but we ended up using an EventEmitter as a proxy.

```
// main.js

var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var emitter = new EventEmitter();
```

Then add it to each request as middleware:

```
// elsewhere in main.js

app.use(function(req, res, next) { 
  req.emitter = emitter;
  next();
});
```

Then in external routes file:

```
// routes.js

exports.addContactPost = function(req, res, err) {
  req.emitter.emit( 'some-key', whatever, data, you, want );
};
```