# how to bind middleware to events in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

Right now you can bind middleware to `io.use(middleware);`, but this is triggered only when a socket connection is made. Is there a way to intercept it before passing it to an event handle like in expressjs?

In other word....

In **express.js** you can do:

```
app.get('/', middleware1, middleware2, function(req, res){
    res.end(); 
});
```

Can I do the same in **socket.io**?

```
socket.on('someEvent', middleware1, middleware2, function(data){
    console.log(data); // data is now filtered by 2 previous middlewares
});
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664184/how-to-pass-changes-from-middleware-to-socket-io

Answer (score 9):

As of Socket.io v2.0.4 (found this while inspecting [this](https://github.com/hden/socketio-wildcard)) you can use a socket middleware like so:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.use((packet, next) => {
    // Handler
    next();
  });
});
```

Which means that you can set your code like so:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.use((packet,next) => {

        if (packet[0] === 'someEvent') {
            if (authorizationCondition) {
                return next(new Error('nope'))
            }
        }
        next();
    })
    socket.on('someEvent', function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
})
```

You will then be able to catch errors like this with a client-side

```
io.on('error', err => { ... }) // err will equal "nope"
```

Answer (score 0):

The npm module [socket.io-events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-events) can help you. The npm repository is well documented.

```
var router = require('socket.io-events')();

// handles all events 
router.on(function (socket, args, next) {
  next();
});

var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
io.use(router);
```