# How can I bind middleware to events in socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using `socket.io` in my nodejs backend server. And I want to set up a middleware for each event. Below is my code:

```
io.use((socket, next) => {
     // some logic
     return next();
});
```

this code only works for the initial connection. It doesn't work on each event in the socket. How can I setup middleware for each socket event?

I have checked this post `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077449/how-to-bind-middleware-to-events-in-socket-io` and `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664184/how-to-pass-changes-from-middleware-to-socket-io`, but they don't do what I need. I want to setup the middleware without changing each event listener.

Comment: I don't think socket.io supports middleware for every event without patching the library or overriding things in the EventEmitter.

Comment: It can be done without modifying the library, and even per event by adding a function defined as a normal event handler (optionally taking as argument an array, stack, of handlers), that serially calls the middle code you want to code and the main code you want to run as your normal event handler. If I do this myself I can share it.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're looking for "wildcard events". I'd personally recommend trying [socketio-wildcard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socketio-wildcard).

**Snippet from that page:**

---

```
npm install --save socketio-wildcard
```

---

```
var io         = require('socket.io')();
var middleware = require('socketio-wildcard')();

io.use(middleware);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('*', function(packet){
    // client.emit('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
    packet.data === ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
  });
});

io.listen(8000);
```

Comment: This is now outdated as of Socket.io v2.0.4, check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077449/how-to-bind-middleware-to-events-in-socket-io